# Java Out of Memory exception in Ubuntu when using Flume/Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, heap-memory, flume

I'm getting an out of memory exception due to lack of Java heap space when I try and download tweets using Flume and pipe them into Hadoop.

I have set the heap space currently to 4GB in the mapred-site.xml of Hadoop, like so:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
</property>
```

I am hoping to download tweets continually for two days but can't get past 45 minutes without errors.

Since I do have the disk space to hold all of this, I am assuming the error is coming from Java having to handle so many things at once. Is there a way for me to slow down the speed at which these tweets are downloaded, or do something else to solve this problem?

**Edit: flume.conf included**

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = <required>
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = <required> 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = <required> 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = manchester united, man united, man utd, man u

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:50070/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

**Edit 2**

I've tried increasing the memory to 8GB which still doesn't help. I am assuming I am placing too many tweets in Hadoop at once and need to write them to disk and release the space again (or something to that effect). Is there a guide anywhere on how to do this?

Comment: Can you post the Java code you are using to download tweets?

Comment: Done - is it an error in there? I modified this code from code provided by Cloudera.

Comment: Usually `-Xmx4096` should also contain the values units so `-Xmx4096m`.

Comment: Apologies, it did contain it, I just copied and pasted the code over poorly. Edited my question now to reflect that.

Comment: When you increase the heap space, you should generally increase the perm-gen size as well (about 25% of the total heap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem had to do with the batch size and transactionCapacity. I changed them to the following:

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 100
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

This works without me even needing to change the JAVA_OPTS value.

Answer (score 1):

Set JAVA_OPTS value at flume-env.sh and start flume agent.